# Can we identify the current element content in HTML?

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to get the content of an HTML element -where the function is called- without having to identify it by ID or class name ?

example instead of using :

```
<button class="colm" type="button" onclick="show('1')">1</button>
```

we use something like :

```
<button class="colm" type="button" onclick="show(getThisElementContent())">1</button>
```

My point is to ask if it's possible to make this function per say we call it `getThisElementContent()` that is able to extraxt the innerHTML from the Element where it is called in our case the element innerHTML is `1`.

Comment: `onclick="show(this);"` (or if you prefer: `show(this.innerText)`)will pass the element triggering the event to the event handler.. but that would be better to fetch as `window.event.target`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple ways, the simplest include:

Passing `this` to the inline event handler:

```js
function showContent(element) {
  console.log(element.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button class="colm" type="button" onclick="showContent(this)">1</button>
```

Adding the event via JS and accessing the event `target`:

```js
document.querySelector('.colm').addEventListener('click', showContent);

function showContent(event) {
  console.log(event.target.textContent);
}
```

```html
<button class="colm" type="button">1</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Sure, define a function named logElem :

```
const logElem = (elem) => console.log({elem});
```

then in HTML :

```
<div onclick="logElem(this)">CLICK ME</div>
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Using the `innerText` proeprty of the target element does the trick.

```js
   let b = document.querySelector('button.colm')
 ;

   b.addEventListener('click', (e) => { console.log(e.target.innerText); });
```

```html
 <button class="colm" type="button">whatever</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. You need to add an event listener in JavaScript so you can handle the mouse click event when it happens.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <button id="myButton">
            Click Me 
        </button>
    </body>
    <script>
        const button = document.getElementById("myButton")
        button.addEventListener('click', e => {
            console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

The second argument to `addEventListener` is a callback function that will get executed when the `click` event happens on the button. This function will receive a parameter, in this case I called it `e` which is of type Event, which you can read about here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event

This Event object has a `target` attribute which is a reference to the object to which the event was originally dispatched, the button.